# Avoid `with` keyword from method name in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am trying to convert my Objective-C code into Swift.
So I have 2 classes, `class A` - converted to Swift, `class B` still in Objective-C.

In my Swift class I have a method `setName(_ name: String)`. But when I try to call it in Obj-C it sees it with `with` keyword, like:

`setNameWithName`

Can I somehow avoid it and just call `[method setName: @"Name"]` without using `with` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify how Obj-C types should see an `@objc` Swift function by supplying the desired function signature in the `@objc()` declaration.

```
@objc(setName:)
func setName(_ name: String) {

}
```